.NET for Android Release Not Building
I am working on creating the Release version of my .NET for Android app. When I select Debug mode, everything builds fine with no problems. However, if I switch to Release mode, I receive errors about my Resources (both the ones defined in this app & another Project that is referenced by this app). I am unable to find any difference at all between the versions, including the Properties & AndroidManifest.xml file. Is there anything (or, more likely, what) that I need to change in any Properties and/or AndroidManifest.xml? This is my first .NET for Android app (all my previous apps were Xamarin.Android), so I am not especially familiar with the changes between the two. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
